# name 'validated_data' is not defined

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize multiple images posted for article in JSON format in DRF

```
class ArticleImagesViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleImages
        fields = ('id','image')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     return ArticleImages.objects.create(**validated_data)


class ArticleViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ArticleImagesViewSerializer(required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption','images')


    def create(self, validated_date):
     images = self.context['request'].FILES.getlist('images')
     articlefinal = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
     for image in list(images):
        m2 = ArticleImages(article=articlefinal, images= image)
        m2.save()
     return articlefinal
```

But i am getting an error that is saying

```
articlea = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
NameError: name 'validated_data' is not defined
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ArticleViewSerializer`

```
def create(self, validated_date):
```

but on this line, you use `validated_data`

```
articlefinal = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Yeah,i made a small typo mistake that i could not notice.Thanks!